# Replace values in pandas dataframe based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one in the form of:

```
#   X   Y   
1   2   0.0 
2   5   0.0 
3   10  0.0 
4   15  0.0 
5   17  0.0 
6   21  0.0
```

and one in the form of:

```
A   B   C   
1   4   2   
2   5   3   
3   6   4
```

I want to replace all the ABC values from the second dataframe, with the X values; so I want go over the ABC df and if the number matches the # of df1 to replace it with the X value

the end table should look:

```
A   B   C   
2   15  5   
5   17  10  
10  21  15
```

is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC `replace`

```
df1.replace(df.set_index('#').X)
Out[382]: 
    A   B   C
0   2  15   5
1   5  17  10
2  10  21  15
```

Answer (score 1):

say your first DataFrame is `a` and your second is `b`, you can map `b` columns to `a.x` values like this:

```py
b.apply(lambda y: a.x[(y -1).tolist()].values)
```

The result is:

```py
    A   B   C
0   2  15   5
1   5  17  10
2  10  21  15
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you should use:

```
df1.set_index('#',inplace = True)
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(df1.loc[x,'X']))
```

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df1['#']=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
df1['X']=[2,5,10,15,17,21]
df1['Y']=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['A']=[1,2,3]
df['B']=[4,5,6]
df['C']=[2,3,4]
df1.set_index('#',inplace = True)
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(df1.loc[x,'X']))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    A   B   C
0   2  15   5
1   5  17  10
2  10  21  15
```

**Note**
`df1.set_index('#',inplace = True)` set `'#'` column like index .
if this column was already the index it is not necessary to execute it